# React hook state - How to turn it to its initial state after a dialog getting displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a dialog component that works fine but once it gets closed can't open it again when I click the same button. Obviously I am not using the hooks state as it should be and missing someting here with the initial state

Here is the code.

```
export const OrderScoreCell = (props) => {
  const { orderDetail } = props;
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleCellClick = (e) => setIsOpen(true);

  return (
    <>
      <TableCell onClick={handleCellClick} lign="left">
        <LightTooltip
          title={`Risco ${orderDetail.scoreDesc}`}
          placement="top-end"
          arrow
          interactive
          TransitionComponent={Fade}
          TransitionProps={{ timeout: 600 }}
          aria-label="score"
        >
        </LightTooltip>
      </TableCell>
      {isOpen && <RiskScoreDialog orderDetail={orderDetail} />}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is `RiskScoreDialog`?  How is it closed?  For example, if it has a button to close it then can you pass `setIsOpen` to the component to update state when that button is clicked?

Comment: RiskScoreDialog is a component and works fine. The close logic is actually inside that component, not here in its parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const handleCellClick = (e) => setIsOpen((prevState)=>!prevState);
```

This is called a functional update. `prevState` is the previous state. So if it is open the `prevState` will be true. You want to close it, so set it to not true (!prevState). If `isOpen = true` then `!prevState = false` and vice versa.

Comment: Hi @Jonas Hendel, it worked! The only thing I noticed is that I need to click twice to reopen the dialog. What do you think is causing the problem? I just applied your suggestion which resolved the issue, but dont know why it needs now a double ckick to get reopened.

Comment: I tried to replicate the error, but it worked for me. So i have to admit, i have no idea.